# filezilla not connecting even with required ports opened

Tags: networking, ssh, ftp, iptables, sftp

Server: Ubuntu 15.04 - 2.6.32-042stab094.8

Client: Windows 10

I did some iptables changes, saved all rules, naturally, reapplied them afterwards, summary of changes are:

**open ports**

- tcp: 20, 21 ,22 ,43, 443
- udp: 123

**defaults policy**

- input - drop
- forward - accept
- output - accept

before changes, default input was accepted thus filezilla connected, etc. after dropping all incoming (except those specified), FZ fails to connect

FZ using SFTP protocol with normal login

**am i missing a required port for sftp to connect?**

**UPDATE**

FILTER TABLE

```
sudo iptables -L -t filter

Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp-data /* FTP-Data IN (iface:ALL) */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp /* FTP-Ctrl IN (iface:ALL) */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh /* SSH IN (iface:ALL) */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:whois /* Whois IN (iface:ALL) */
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ntp /* NTP IN (iface:ALL) */
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             /* Ping Request/Reply IN (iface:ALL) */

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             /* Ping Request/Reply OUT (iface:ALL) */

Chain LOGGING (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

NAT TABLE

```
sudo iptables -L -t nat


Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
SNAT       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             to:x.x.x.x <- server ip
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: What is the output of `sudo iptables -L`? Make sure you put the drop policy AFTER all other rules.

Comment: i flush iptables with accept in all chains, add rules, and thereafter drop all other input packets, i tested it now with my android device using turbo client, it conencts perfectly, on windows I and my colleague have the same issue of filezilla not connecting, filezxilla works when policy is accepted, fz does not work when input is dropped, hence it uses a non-mentioned port, check update for iptables output

Comment: You're sure you're using SFTP when testing both Filezilla and the Turbo client on Android? FTPS is NOT the same as SFTP.